# In spring batch integration does master share equal partitions to slaves or can we share particular partitions to particular nodes

Tags: spring-integration, spring-batch

I have implemented spring batch integration with remote partitioning. in this I have separate nodes(2 nodes).

each node have same slave and master config. i will trigger batch from node1 or node2.

let say i triggered from node1 so the master at node1 has to distribute few partitions to node1 slave and few to node2 slave.

In a table I have ids 1-2000. In 1st partition I have 1-100. 2nd partition 101-200 so on.

so from these p0 to p10 should go to node1, p11 to p20 should go to node2.
how should i configure this.

if you need my config to know i will post

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the number of workers (and many others parameters actually). In your example, you have 20 partitions. If you create 20 workers, chances are each partition will be processed by a worker, but this is not guaranteed. In remote partitioning, the partitioner creates execution contexts with partitions meta-data and send them on a queue (as `StepExecutionRequest`s). Now, how these execution requests are distributed across workers (ie, how they are picked up by workers from the queue) is what answers your question.

Comment: thank you mahmoud
actually i donot know how requests picked up by workers. i will look into that.

Comment: does it possible to share partitions equally among all slaves with our changes in code.